# populate input fields with JSON Object value

Tags: php, json, forms, input

First off, apologies, I am not a php expert in anyway and I am struggling with this, but I have an entry in a DB that is in JSON format.

I am trying to then extract the values from this object into a series of input boxes.

after using:

```
$response = json_decode($row['responseJSON']);
```

where responseJSON is the name of my table, I return the following object:

```
stdClass Object ( [fields] => stdClass Object ( [marketingID] => stdClass Object ( [attributes] => stdClass Object ( [type] => hidden [id] => marketingID [value] => 0 ) [value] => 7 ) [marketingTelephone] => stdClass Object ( [attributes] => stdClass Object ( [type] => text [class] => form-control [id] => marketingTelephone [required] => true [label] => Telephone ) [value] => +44 123 456789 ) [marketingEmail] => stdClass Object ( [attributes] => stdClass Object ( [type] => email [class] => form-control [id] => marketingEmail [required] => true [placeholder] => you@company.com ) [value] => contact@helloworld.com ) ) [files] => stdClass Object ( [marketingLogo] => stdClass Object ( [name] => logo1.png [path] => /resources\logo1.png [size] => 2408 [mime] => [attributes] => stdClass Object ( [id] => marketingLogo [type] => file [label] => Choose File ) ) ) )
```

and input boxes:

```
<perch:input id="marketingLogo" type="file" label="Choose File" />
<perch:input type="text" class="form-control" id="marketingTelephone" required="true"  label="Telephone" />
<perch:input type="email" class="form-control" id="marketingEmail" required="true" placeholder="you@company.com" />
```

My issue is, I am trying to traverse the object using:

```
json_o->marketingID (and various versions) but to no avail.
```

I then thought, maybe I need to go about it along the route of:

```
foreach ($response as $object) {
   {
    foreach ($object as $property=>$value)
      {...
```

but too be brutally honest, this is all getting over my head as I just do not quite understand how I need to traverse everything to get to the values given in the object.

I hope this makes sense and I apologise for the lack of knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you decode JSON into array rather than object. This can be achieved by supplying a second argument (true) to json_decode as:

```
$response = json_decode($row['responseJSON'], true);
```

This should work with foreach blocks

Comment: Thanks, I tried thay, but just couldn't understand how to properly interrogate the for each loops to drill down to the values I wanted.

Comment: In fact you may not need foreach blocks at all. You can access nested elements like follows (for example to access attributes of MarketingTelephone): $response['fields']['marketingTelephone']['attributes']